# comparing groupby with column (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

i have data set like this

```
       data=pd.DataFrame({'year':[2011,2011,2011,2011,2012,2012,2012,2012,],
               'party':['a','a','b','b','a','a','b','b'],
               'vote':[5,3,2,1,1,2,4,3],
               'area':['cali','ny','cali','ny','cali','ny','cali','ny']})
```

we can see when ever cali votes to party it gets elected how to get this
code I am using

```
           df1=data.groupby(['year','party'],as_index=False)['vote'].sum()

          df1.loc[df1.groupby(['year'])['vote'].idxmax()].reset_index()
```

i want see which area voted for winning party? i hope you understood my question

further explanation

[image]

i want to see area which are always voting for winning parties

Comment: what is your expected output from the given dataframe?

Comment: added further explanation ,i want to see areas which are always voting for winning parties

Comment: @Nk03 no that doesnt work.

Comment: What are `x` and `y`? I'm confused by "i want see which area voted for winning party". In this example everywhere _always_ votes for the winning party, as both cali and ny have votes for the winning party every year. Cam you clarify output without placeholder variables.

Comment: @HenryEcker i am providing the data and my work please have a look https://github.com/sprabhala-cpu/stack

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

You can try:

```
df1=data.groupby(['year','party'],as_index=False)['vote'].sum()
df1=df1.loc[df1.groupby(['year'])['vote'].idxmax(),['year','party']].set_index('year')
```

Now use `map()` method:

```
data['party']=data['year'].map(df1['party'])
```

Finally:

```
out=data.groupby(['year','party','area']).agg({'vote':'sum'})
```

If needed:

```
out=out.drop('vote',1)
```

Now if you print `out` you will get your expected output

Comment: @sra did you get your expected output?

Comment: no it doesnt work  if you want to try i can share the dataset.with this  code I am also getting areas which are not consistent with winning party

Comment: you can find data here https://github.com/sprabhala-cpu/stack